# Creating a Penrose tiling procedural material

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm trying to create a procedural texture of a Penrose tiling using the node editor but I don't even know where to start with this one. This what a Penrose tiling looks like.

[image]

It's an aperiodic tiling meaning it doesn't repeat so how to tile them is way above my understanding of Blender. I want to be able to choose the colour of the shapes (kites and darts) and apply the texture on a plane.

I found some [articles on how to make them as meshes](https://cgfromspace.blogspot.com/2013/11/penrose-tiling-in-blender-building.html) but it's not really what I want since I plan on subdividing the planes later so I can rig them for origami.

Comment: I checked out that website earlier but the problem is it works by generating a bunch of edges on a decagon. I probably should of also specified I wanted to place the pattern on a _square_ plane. The main issue is it would be difficult to rig for origami as there would be so many faces already.

Comment: I think you may be able to achieve it using shader nodes, but you'll most likely end up with an unmaintainable monster tree. IMO the method you linked to is what you should use, and then you can bake the resulting material onto your simple plane

Comment: Thanks for the idea. When I put the script into the console it returned a few errors. Apparently the API changed since than. Luckily someone in the comment section of the website already noticed this and wrote what to change some lines to. I'll see what I can do with this.

Comment: Yup just tested, replace l.83 with `bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(ob)` and l.87 with `mesh.validate()`

Comment: Here's a [blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aZN8gvBA/) that has your starting point.